# How do you say: "People like you are ____" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles

I know より is used to make comparisons, but it seems like that wouldn't be the correct choice, in this scenario. I'm not sure if I would use it to say "People (like/similar to) you are ____".

I know the difference between saying "人は魚が好きだ" and "魚が好きな人", and I want to specify people who behave like whoever is being referred to, rather than all people in general. For example, saying something like: "People like you, who st

When I say like/similar to, I'm referring to behavior/personality. So I'm not sure if I'd have to word it like "You behave/have a similar personality to a certain type of person"

If I try to say: "You are like people who behaves poorly", I think it might be something like:

(あなた/name) +と+ 振る舞いが悪い人みたいだ。

I'm still trying to learn, so I'm probably way off.

Would saying something like "People (thieves) like you are the worst", be as simple as saying is as "You and thieves are the worst" instead.

person ＋と＋ 泥棒は最悪です

Is there anyone who could give me a few examples, or link me to a guide that might clear this up?

Answer (score 2):

Please forget より for now. より for "comparison" is used in the context of `more ～ than ～`, as in "He is taller than me" or "It's more expensive". To say "like ～" or "similar to ～", you have to use a completely different construction. You can use:

- [ような](http://maggiesensei.com/2012/04/03/request-lesson-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86you/)
- [みたいな](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/11/11/how-to-use-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-mitai/)

Examples:

- 君のような人は嫌いです。
  君みたいな人は嫌いです。
  I don't like someone like you.
- 君は悪い人のようだ。
  君は悪い人みたいだ。
  You're like a villain.

Comment: What about 似る? Would you say 君に似た人, or again 君に似る人? Would there be a difference with ような/みたいな?

Comment: @Rightleg It's grammatical, but I don't hear something like that. (Is it natural to say "I hate someone who resembles you" in English?)

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough!